# Show that $N(Q)=N(P)-1$ where $N(P)$ is the number of strictly positive roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $P$ be a real polynomial and $N(P)$ the number of strictly postive roots of $P$ 
Let $n$ be an integer and suppose $P= \sum_{0}^{n} a_{k}X^{b_{k}}$ where $b_{0}=0$ and $b_{i}$ is an increasing sequence of positive integers.
A certain polynomial $Q$ exists such that $$P'=X^{b_{1}-1}Q$$
Show that $N(Q)=N(P)-1$. 
It is clear that $N(Q)=N(P')$ since the roots have to be strictly positive i.e different than $0$, to show that $N(P')=N(P)-1$ I thought of using Rolle's theorem where between two roots of $P$ there exist a root of $P'$ however I need to prove no additional roots come from elsewhere. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P=X^4-2X^2+2 = (X^2-1)^2+1 \ \ $. We have $\ N(P)=0$.

$P' = XQ \ \ $, with $\ Q=4(X^2-1) \ $. So $N(Q)=1 \ $.

And $N(Q)$ is not equal to $N(P)-1$ ...